# extracting data from a nested table JSON file in Jetpack Compose

Tags: json, database, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I know how to extract a data from a table in Json but I am struggling when this table is nested.
I have tried various ways but cannot figure out where is the problem.

The JSON file :

```
[
    {
        "planetId": "earth_id",
        "planetName": "Earth",
        "planetTranslations": [
            {
                "planetTransSpa": "Tierra"
            },
            {
                "planetTransFre": "Terre"
            },
            {
                "planetTransIta": "Terra"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "planetId": "mars_id",
        "planetName": "Mars",
        "planetTranslations": [
            {
                "planetTransSpa": "Marte"
            },
            {
                "planetTransFre": "Mars"
            },
            {
                "planetTransIta": "Marte"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My data class

```
@Serializable
@Entity(tableName = "Planets")
data class PlanetItem(
    @PrimaryKey val planetId: String,
    @ColumnInfo val planetName: String,
    @ColumnInfo val planetTransSpa: String,
    @ColumnInfo val planetTransFre: String,
    @ColumnInfo val planetTransIta: String
)
```

When I try to extract the data from the nested table in Jetpack Compose (not working)

```
Text(
 text = uiState?.planetTransSpa?: ""
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong data classes to parse to it!!
you must have these data classes in order to parse it:

```
data class PlanetResponse(
    val planets: List<Planet>
)

data class Planet(
    val planetId: String,
    val planetName: String,
    val planetTranslations: List<PlanetTranslation>
)

data class PlanetTranslation(
    val planetTransSpa: String?,
    val planetTransFre: String?,
    val planetTransIta: String?
)
```

and now for your Api point you gonna have to make it return a `PlanetResponse` instance.

***Bonus: in Android studio you can add a plugin called **Json To Kotlin class** which you provide a json response to it and it will create the nessecary data classes automatically***

Comment: It makes sense now thanks to your solution, since I have 2 tables. I download that plugin

Comment: Just downloaded it now. Huge time saving plugin in perspective. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MisterPropre yeah i feel you first time when I downloaded it, it felt like a game changing feature